# Cmdlet in PowerShell to know the OutputFiles generated by a ADLA JOB

Tags: powershell, azure-data-lake, azure-automation

Is there a cmdlet in PowerShell to know the OutputFiles generated by a ADLA JOB.

The following CMDLET does not seem to offer that information:

```
Get-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob [-Account] <String> [-JobId] <Guid> [[-Include] <ExtendedJobData>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Thanks,

Ankit

Comment: Can you define/specify what you mean by "know the OutputFiles"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn't a direct way of via any of the cmdlets to enumerate the inputs or outputs of a job. It could be derived though by looking at the algebra.xml that each job produces.

We *are* building an REST API/SDK methods/cmdlet that would provide this list of inputs and outpus. This feature will arrive before sometime between now (June 2017) and December 2017.